ValueError: User preference vector and restaurant feature vectors must have the same number of dimensions
I'm building a restaurant recommendation system in Python using user preferences (cuisine, price range) and cosine similarity. I'm encountering a ValueError: User preference vector and restaurant feature vectors must have the same number of dimensions. Error under two scenarios:
Scenario 1:
I'm using one-hot encoding for cuisine types in the restaurant data.
When building the user preference vector, the get_user_preferences function considers both cuisine and price range (if provided).
The error occurs when the user selects "all" cuisines (one-hot encoded vector with all features as 1).
Scenario 2:
The error occurs even when the user selects a specific cuisine (one-hot encoded vector with a single feature as 1).
I suspect there might be a mismatch in how cuisines are represented in the user preference vector and the restaurant data (e.g., single cuisine vs. list of cuisines).
2. Define User Preference Function
def get_user_preferences(cuisine=None, price_range=None):
Initialize an empty preference vector
user_pref = [0] * len(encoder.get_feature_names_out())
Set cuisine preference (one-hot encoding)
if cuisine:
cuisine_index = encoder.get_feature_names_out().tolist().index(cuisine)
user_pref[cuisine_index] = 1
Set price range
if price_range:
user_pref.append(price_range)  # Assuming price range is a numerical value
return user_pref
def get_user_preferences(cuisine=None, price_range=None):
ist: User preference vector with one-hot encoded cuisine and price range.
"""
# Initialize an empty preference vector with an equal preference for all cuisines
num_cuisines = len(encoder.get_feature_names_out())
user_pref = [1 / num_cuisines] * num_cuisines
# Set cuisine preference (one-hot encoding)
if cuisine:
    cuisine_index = encoder.get_feature_names_out().tolist().index(cuisine)
    user_pref[cuisine_index] = 1

# Set price range
if price_range:
    user_pref.append(price_range)  # Assuming price range is a numerical value

return user_pref

#3
def cosine_similarity(user_pref, restaurant_vec):
# Extract cuisine vectors from user preference and restaurant vectors
user_pref_cuisine = user_pref[:-1] if len(user_pref) > 1 else user_pref  # Exclude price range if available
restaurant_vec_cuisine = restaurant_vec[:-1] if len(restaurant_vec) > 1 else restaurant_vec
Check that the user_pref_cuisine and restaurant_vec_cuisine vectors have the same length
if len(user_pref_cuisine) != len(restaurant_vec_cuisine):
    raise ValueError("User preference cuisine vector and restaurant cuisine vector must have the same number of dimensions.")

# Calculate cosine similarity
return np.dot(user_pref_cuisine, restaurant_vec_cuisine) / (np.linalg.norm(user_pref_cuisine) * np.linalg.norm(restaurant_vec_cuisine))

def get_user_preferences_from_user():
"""
This function prompts the user to choose their preferred cuisine and price range.
Returns:
    List: User preference vector with one-hot encoded cuisine and price range.
"""
# Get user input for cuisine
available_cuisines = list(df['Cuisines'].unique())  # Assuming unique cuisines are in a column
while True:
    cuisine = input("Enter your preferred cuisine (or 'all' for any): ").lower().strip()
    if cuisine in available_cuisines or cuisine == 'all':
        break
    else:
        print(f"Invalid cuisine. Available options are: {', '.join(available_cuisines)}")

# Get user input for the price range
price_ranges = {
    "1": "Cheap",
    "2": "Moderate",
    "3": "Fine Dining"
}
while True:
    price_range = input("Enter your preferred price range (1 - Cheap, 2 - Moderate, 3 - Fine Dining): ")
    if price_range in price_ranges:
        break
    else:
        print(f"Invalid price range. Please enter 1, 2, or 3.")

# Encode cuisine (if not 'all')
if cuisine != 'all':
    cuisine_index = encoder.get_feature_names_out().tolist().index(cuisine)
    user_pref = [0] * len(encoder.get_feature_names_out())
    user_pref[cuisine_index] = 1
else:
    user_pref = [1] * len(encoder.get_feature_names_out())  # One-hot encode for all cuisines

# Add price range if specified
if price_range:
    user_pref.append(int(price_range))

# Ensure that the user preference vector has the same number of features as the restaurant feature vectors
if len(user_pref) != len(df.drop(columns=['Restaurant Name']).values[0]):
    raise ValueError("User preference vector and restaurant feature vectors must have the same number of dimensions.")

return user_pref

4. Recommend Restaurants
def recommend_restaurants(user_pref, df=df, top_n=5):
"""
This function recommends restaurants based on user preferences and similarity scores.
Args:
user_pref (list): User preference vector.
df (pandas.DataFrame, optional): Preprocessed restaurant data. Defaults to df.
top_n (int, optional): Number of top recommendations to return. Defaults to 5.
Returns:
pandas.DataFrame: Top N recommended restaurants with details.
"""
# Construct restaurant feature vectors including encoded cuisines
restaurant_feature_vectors = df.drop(columns=['Restaurant Name']).values
# Check if the user preference vector and restaurant feature vectors have the same number of dimensions
if len(user_pref) != len(restaurant_feature_vectors[0]):
    raise ValueError("User preference vector and restaurant feature vectors must have the same number of dimensions.")

# Calculate similarity scores for each restaurant
similarities = np.array([cosine_similarity(user_pref, vec) for vec in restaurant_feature_vectors])

# Sort restaurants by similarity score (descending)
df_sorted = df.assign(similarity=similarities).sort_values(by='similarity', ascending=False)

# Return top N recommendations
return df_sorted.head(top_n).drop('similarity', axis=1)

Assuming you have a function to get user input for cuisine and price range
user_pref = get_user_preferences_from_user()  # Replace with your function
Call the recommend_restaurants function with your data and user preferences
recommendations = recommend_restaurants(user_pref, df=df)  # Use your data in df
print("Top Restaurant Recommendations:")
print(recommendations)
Enter your preferred cuisine (or 'all' for any): all
Enter your preferred price range (1 - Cheap, 2 - Moderate, 3 - Fine Dining): 4
Invalid price range. Please enter 1, 2, or 3.
Enter your preferred price range (1 - Cheap, 2 - Moderate, 3 - Fine Dining): 1
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in <cell line: 2>()
1 # Assuming you have a function to get user input for cuisine and price range
----> 2 user_pref = get_user_preferences_from_user()  # Replace with your function
3
4 # Call the recommend_restaurants function with your data and user preferences
5 recommendations = recommend_restaurants(user_pref, df=df)  # Use your data in df
 in get_user_preferences_from_user()
42     # Ensure that the user preference vector has the same number of features as the restaurant feature vectors
43     if len(user_pref) != len(df.drop(columns=['Restaurant Name']).values[0]):
---> 44         raise ValueError("User preference vector and restaurant feature vectors must have the same number of dimensions.")
45
46     return user_pref
ValueError: User preference vector and restaurant feature vectors must have the same number of dimensions.

This post addresses potential causes and fixes for issues that might arise in the provided cosine similarity function:

Non-numerical Data Types:

Problem: The user_pref or restaurant_vec might contain strings or non-numerical data types.
Fix: Convert these values to floats using a list comprehension:
Python
user_pref = [float(x) for x in user_pref]

Empty Vectors:

Problem: The np.linalg.norm function can raise errors with empty vectors (all zeros).
Fix: The code includes a check for this, but consider improving clarity.
Improved Code Snippet:
Python
def cosine_similarity(user_pref, restaurant_vec):
Ensure vectors have the same dimensions (padding with zeros if necessary)
... (unchanged padding logic)
Check for empty vectors
if not any(user_pref) or not any(restaurant_vec):
return 0  # Avoid division by zero
Convert to NumPy arrays for efficiency (consider alternative for small datasets)
user_pref = np.array(user_pref, dtype=float)
restaurant_vec = np.array(restaurant_vec, dtype=float)
return np.dot(user_pref, restaurant_vec) / (np.linalg.norm(user_pref)

thank you for your solution but this dosen't work.... same issue persisted....
